# Inserted text in tasks

Tags: exsheets, tasks

I'm using the great [exsheets](http://ctan.org/pkg/exsheets) and [tasks](http://ctan.org/pkg/tasks) packages to create my exercises.

I want the follow: in environment `tasks` insert plus text, which is not part of task (plus instruction or information). For example please see this image

[image]

An MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[load-tasks]{exsheets}
\begin{document}
  \begin{question}
  Az $ABC$ hegyesszögű... 
  \begin{tasks}
    \task Számítsa ki a $BC$ oldalhoz...
    \task Számítsa ki az $AB$...
    \plustext{Válaszait cm-ben... <<< How can I do it? >>>}
    \plustext{Az $AB$ oldal... <<< How can I do it? >>>}
    \task Határozza meg...
  \end{tasks}
  \end{question}
\end{document}
```

How can I imitate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\task`s are like items and the `tasks` environment support the `resume` option.

So, you can write:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[load-tasks]{exsheets}
\begin{document}
  \begin{question}
  Az $ABC$ hegyesszögű...
  \begin{tasks}
    \task Számítsa ki a $BC$ oldalhoz...
    \task Számítsa ki az $AB$...
  \end{tasks}
  Válaszait cm-ben... \\
  Az $AB$ oldal... 
  \begin{tasks}[resume=true]
    \task Határozza meg...
  \end{tasks}
  \end{question}
\end{document}
```

and the output will be:

[image]